# I've been working on a discord bot for at least a week and just today, my joke command started saying invalid syntax

Tags: bots, discord.py

I have been working on a discord.py bot when yesterday, on my bus, some of my code got deleted. Everything was working fine, but now my joke command doesn't work. I am pretty new to coding as this is my 2nd week, but can someone explain to me why this says invalid syntax?

```
@bot.command()
async def joke(ctx):
    responses = [
     "Two hunters are out in the woods when one of them collapses. He's not breathing so his friend calls 911. My friend is dead! What should I do? The operator replies, Calm down sir, first make sure that he's really dead. There's a silence, then a loud bang. Back on the phone, the guy says, Ok, now what?",
     "I threw a boomerang a few years ago; now I live in constant fear.",
     "Someone stole my mood ring. I don't know how I feel about that.",
   "Women call me ugly until they find out how much money I make. Then they call me ugly and poor.",
   "You're not completely useless: you can serve as a bad example.",
   "I broke my finger last week. On the other hand, I'm okay.",
     "Appearantly someone in London gets stabbed every 52 seconds. Poor bastard.",
     "A Roman legionaire walks into a bar, holds up two fingers, and says, Five Beers please!"
 await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a closing bracket at the end of your list.

Comment: OH LOL! Thank you so much.